# Dynamic conversion of Array of double columns into multiple columns in nested spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My current DataFrame looks like as below:

```
{"id":"1","inputs":{"values":{"0.2":[1,1],"0.4":[1,1],"0.6":[1,1]}},"id1":[1,2]}
```

I want to transform this dataframe into the below dataFrame:

```
{"id":"1", "v20":[1,1],"v40":[1,1],"v60":[1,1],"id1":[1,2]}
```

This means that, each 'values' array's items (0.2, 0.4 and 0.6) will be multiplied by 100, prepended with the letter 'v', and extracted into separate columns.

How does the code would look like in order to achieve this. I have tried `withColumn` but couldn't achieve this.

Comment: those columns are fixed, or it could be also 0.7?

Comment: Is this one single line of your data or the whole JSON dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code and please find the inline comments for the code explanation

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

object DynamicCol {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    val df = spark.read.json("src/main/resources/dyamicCol.json")    /// Load the JSON file
    val dfTemp = df.select(col("inputs.values").as("values")) // Temp Dataframe for fetching the nest values
    val index = dfTemp
      .schema.fieldIndex("values")
    val propSchema = dfTemp.schema(index).dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
    val dfFinal = propSchema.fields.foldLeft(df)( (df,field) => {     // Join Dataframe with the list of nested columns
      val colNameInt = (field.name.toDouble * 100).toInt
      val colName = s"v$colNameInt"
      df.withColumn(colName,col("inputs.values.`" + field.name + "`"))  // Add the nested column mappings
    }  ).drop("inputs") // Drop the extra column

    dfFinal.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).json("src/main/resources/dyamicColOut.json") // Output the JSON file
  }

}
```

Comment: Can we optimize it further ... I see major performance issues in this as we are creating dataframe multiple times ...

Comment: No. of Dataframes created does not reflects the performance of any Spark Job becuase they lazily evaluated in the case above it would happen on line dfFinal.write. call @user2046073

Answer (score 0):

I would make the logic for the change of column name splitter into 2 parts, the one that is a numeric value, and the one that doesn't change.

```
def stringDecimalToVNumber(colName:String): String =
  "v" + (colName.toFloat * 100).toInt.toString
```

and form a single function that transforms according to the case

```
val floatRegex = """(\d+\.?\d*)""".r
def transformColumnName(colName:String): String = colName match {
  case floatRegex(v) => stringDecimalToVNumber(v) //it's a float, transform it
  case x => x // keep it
```

now we have the function to transform the end of the columns, let's pick the schema dynamicly.

```
val flattenDF = df.select("id","inputs.values.*")

val finalDF = flattenDF
  .schema.names
  .foldLeft(flattenDF)((dfacum,x) => {
    val newName = transformColumnName(x)
    if (newName == x)
      dfacum // the name didn't need to be changed
    else 
      dfacum.withColumnRenamed(x, transformColumnName(x))
  })
```

This will dynamically transform all the columns inside inputs.values to the new name, and put them in next to id.

Comment: This is not working ,,,  error is No such struct field values in 0.1, 0.5, 0.9 ... another issue is that  there is hardcoded df("id") ... in my case columns are quite variable.

Comment: There was a missing parethesis in the map of columnsTransformed. Also, yeah, that error is because the only way to select or reference a column with a numeric name like '0.2' is in the method withColumnRenamed. I'm updating the solution